# How to make multiple roles in Spatie Laravel package?

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

Is possible with Spatie's [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package to achieve something like what Facebook have with their permissions for pages?

#### Case study,

On Facebook you can create a page, then automatically you'll become **Admin** (*assuming it's a role*) of that page.
Then you can invite you friend and make him/her a **Publisher** role

After that, your friend can also invite you to their Page and make you an **Editor** ( *that's another role for you*)

so at the end you will have two roles for two different profiles/Pages.

I want to achieve something like that on my app.

#### EDIT

what i know for now is that i can use:

```
$user->assignRole('editor');
```

and i can check if the user has a roles with :

```
$user->hasRole('writer')
```

But the thing is how do i link that role with the page that i want them to manage?

Like if you have admin role in one page and editor role in another page.
and if you just check if `$user->hasRole('admin')` the results will always be true. so i want to know if there is anything i can do to assign and also check which page are you admin for.

I hope i am making sense.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you share what you have?

Comment: i have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table structure looks like this:

**Pages table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       name       |   created_at     |   updated_at     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    PHP masters   |    2019-02-31    |   2019-03-12     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

**Pages admin**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |      page_id     |      role_id     |     user_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         12       |         2        |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

**Roles table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       name       |   created_at     |   updated_at     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |      Editor      |    2019-02-31    |   2019-03-12     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |   System Admin   |    2019-02-31    |   2019-03-12     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         |    Page Admin    |    2019-02-31    |   2019-03-12     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

**Now inside User model add this method**

```
#do not forget to import Roles
#use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

    public function can_manage($page_id) : bool;
    {

        #Backdoor for the system admin
        if ($this->hasRole(['System Admin'])) {
            return true;
        }


        #now we check if the user has the role for that page
        $role = Role::select('name')
                        ->join("page_admins", 'page_admins.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
                        ->where("page_id", $page_id)
                        ->where("user_id",   $this->id)
                        ->first();


        #return true if roles was found
        if (!empty($role)) {
            return true;
        }


        #else false
        return false;


    }
```

Lastly if you want to check if the user can access the page's admin you use:

```
#for jwt-auth
#$user = $request->user(); 

if ( $user->can_manage($page_id) )
{
   #then do you things
}
```

Now that you saw how to check if someone is among page administration, you can get creative with that. you can create a method that :

```
#Get user role in the page
#etc
```

Comment: Finally someone took their time to help. thanks @chawila

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. You can create the roles with artisan and assign them in php.

```
php artisan permission:create-role editor
php artisan permission:create-role publisher
```

```php
$user->assignRole(['editor', 'publisher']);
```

all of this is easily available in the [documentation](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/)

Comment: I think you did not understand the **Q**, please read again i have updated it.

Comment: You can achieve this by using a hasMany relationship between your Admin/User model and Page model. A page can have many users/admins. You maintain/control what a user can do, by defining permissions for every operation/action. You can then assign these permissions to the roles you've created.